# Row bind tibbles with the same name within a list of several lists

Tags: r, purrr, nested-lists, tibble

I have a list containing several lists each containing 4 tibbles named "A", "B", "C", "D":

```
list_1[["A"]], list_1[["B"]], list_1[["C"]], list_1[["D"]]
list_2[["A"]], list_2[["B"]], list_2[["C"]], list_2[["D"]]
list_3[["A"]], list_3[["B"]], list_3[["C"]], list_3[["D"]] etc.

all_lists <- list(list_1, list_2, list_3, .etc.)
```

All of those tibbes have the same amount of columns and I would like to row bind all [["A"]] tibbles, all [["B"]] tibbles of the lists and so on.

I'm pretty sure this is something for the `map()` function family of purrr but have no clue how to tell map() to only use `rbind()` on specific tibbles within those lists (i.e. tibbles with the same name). Or is this something for the `reduce()` function?

I would be thankful for any advice!

Comment: Is the order always the same (A,B,C,D..etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with

```
all_lists <- map_depth(all_lists, 2, ~.x %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))
```

to make sure that rowbind would work and then

```
new_list <- all_lists %>% 
  pmap(bind_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the order is always alphabetically similar, you could use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
list_1  <- list("A" = mtcars[1,1:5], "B" =  mtcars[1,1:2], "C" = mtcars[1,1:3])
list_2 <- list("A" = mtcars[2,1:5], "B" = mtcars[2:5,1:2], "C"= mtcars[1:10,1:3])

list_comb <- map2(list_1, list_2, rbind)
```